# issue with target="_content" from sidebar

Tags: firefox

Firefox main window is refreshing always if a hyper link which differs only
in the HASH part is clicked from the sidebar. I am using target="_content"
to achieve this.

Main window url = "www.mydomain.com/index.html".
The hyperlink in my sidebar is "www.mydomain.com/index.html#search=testing"

I noticed this if firefox is started with some particular profile only.

Why this behavior?
Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

The 'HASH part' you refer to is an anchor.

I'm not sure if the syntax `www.mydomain.com/index.html#search=testing` is valid.

There is no mention of it at the W3C HTML 4.0 Recommendation about the [syntax of anchor names](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#h-12.2.1)